# Override the grid of customer magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-grid

I want to override the grid of customer to delete some columns from and add others so how to proceed. I overrided the customer_listing.xml but no result

Answer (score 1):

Try adding sequence to your module.xml if your overriding is not working.

```
 <sequence>
      <module name="Magento_Customer" />
 </sequence>
```

In your overrided file, you can specify the column visibility to either true or false (to hide and show the columns). However manually setting the column visibility in admin grid will take more priority.

```
<visible>false</visible>
```

Comment: i want to export the list with the colunm that i want so if i set manually  the colunm visisbility they will appear in the file.csv

Comment: no result even added the sequence

Comment: If your objective is to show only the visible columns in export CSV, it seems this feature is not available in magento 2 right now. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3079

Comment: so do i have to delete some attributes from customer entity ??

Comment: No thats not a good idea